# QFileDialog filter out paths based on location

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I have a QFileDialog and I want to filter out all paths that are not in ~/Documents.

Current have

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import os

...
dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(...)
dialog.setDirectory(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents"))
dialog.setProxyModel(MyFilter())
selectedPath = dialog.exec_()

...

class MyFilter(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):

   def filterAcceptsRow(self, p_int, QModelIndex):
       sourceModel = self.sourceModel()
       index = sourceModel.index(p_int, 0,QModelIndex)
       path = sourceModel.filePath(index)
       return self._inside_documents_or_is_ancestor(path)

   def _inside_documents_or_is_ancestor(self, path):
        docpath = os.path.expanduser("~/Documents")
        if path.startswith(docpath) or docpath.startswith(path):
            print True, path, docpath
            return True
        return False
```

It seems like none of the paths are being filtered since I can choose any file in my filesystem in the QFileDialog.

I'm not sure about details of filterAcceptsRow(), but it seems that if I reject a directory, its subdirectories will not be considered, that's why I'm accepting those paths that ancestors of my desired path.

I am running pyqt 5.1 and python 2.7.5

Comment: Have you checked with print if the return value is OK in those cases when you select such a path?

Comment: updated to more closely reflect my scenario. Confused as to the affects of filterAcceptsRow(), if I use a blanket "return False" I can still see my filesystem and select items just fine

Comment: I do not see in your code that you are actually using that filter anywhere for starter.

Comment: ok added, it was in the original code I ran

Comment: according to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow , return True if you want the item to be included. Edited code, but I'm setting the proxy model and calling <QfileDialog instance>.exec_()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44196/discussion-between-mingxiao-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment discussion, I think your condition is simply wrong.

You are using `os.path.startswith` which will include all the subfolders as well, naturally. Your question writes those would need to be kept. Naturally, your condition is incorrect respectively.

You should write something like this instead:

```
if os.path.dirname(path) == docpath:
    return False
```

Please note that you also returned `True` for your condition which inherently means, nothing will really get filtered out as you would like to have it.

Furthermore, I would consider this as a usability issue eventually in your user interface design. Users would not be able to browse into that folder unless they start typing the whole path. A much better UX approach (in my opinion for sure) would be to actually allow them to browse, and warn them later if they wish to select a file from that particular folder.